# Retrieve Year from week number

Tags: datetime, delphi, delphi-xe, week-number

Using Embarcadero Delphi, I need to populate a table with week number and the week year.
The problem is at the end of December and starting January.

First case:
Date "29/12/2024": is in the year 2024 and is referred to the 52° week of 2024.
So I'll insert a record like:
WEEK NUMBER = 52
WEEK YEAR = 2024

Second case:
Date "30/12/2024": is in the year 2024 but is referred to the 1° week of 2025.
So I need to insert a record like:
WEEK NUMBER = 1
WEEK YEAR = 2025

How can I calculate this dynamically? Monday is the first date of the week

Comment: See `System.DateUtils.WeekOf`.

Comment: Also beware that week numbers are different in US and Europe. In Europe, the first Thursday in January is week 1. I believe the function @TomBrunberg mentions is the ISO standard (Europe). I'm not sure if Delphi contains a US-conforming one as well.

Comment: And week starting day is also different: US = Sunday, ISO (Europe) = Monday.

Comment: @HeartWare What OP describes is according to ISO.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Check. Didn't check up on - just wanted to point it out...

Comment: @TomBrunberg WeekOf works with input year and I need it as result

Comment: Yes of course, that is why I wrote it as a comment. But you need it to know **when you need to adjust the year**, just like @HeartWare does in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this procedure:

```
USES System.DateUtils;

PROCEDURE GetWeek(D : TDate ; OUT Week,Year : Cardinal);
  BEGIN
    Week:=WeekOf(D); Year:=YearOf(D);
    CASE MonthOf(D) OF
       1 : IF Week>50 THEN DEC(Year);
      12 : IF Week<50 THEN INC(Year)
    END
  END;
```

It will return the Week and the corresponding Year for any given date in the Julian Calendar.

Comment: Just a minor matter: To keep compatibility with other date and time functions (ex. `EncodeDate()`, `MonthOf()`etc.), I would use `word` instead of `cardinal`. `Out` parameters must be exactly the same type.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: I'll leave that up to the user of the procedure. Personally, I think the use of Word (16-bit!) in a 32-bit application is wrong, but hey! :-)

Comment: HeartWare is trying to avoid the Year 65536 Problem.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: :-)